# Transforming SQL to JPA QL

Tags: sql, jql

I have an SQL query that joins three tables. Where I would like to select all the projects for a users accounts.

i.e. Give me all the projects for a particular user...

User => Accounts (many to many), Accounts => Projects (1 to many)

The User => Accounts many to many is managed using a join table.

This is my SQL

```
select UA.user_id, m.PROJECT_ID, m.name, m.description
 from Project AS m INNER JOIN Account
 AS a on m.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
    INNER JOIN User_Account UA ON a.ACCOUNT_ID = UA.ACCOUNT_ID
        WHERE UA.USER_ID = ?1
```

Which returns the projects.

I want to transform this query into JPA QL, but really do not know where to start, can anyone help?

Thanks

Solution:

```
select distinct p from Project, Account a, User u join a.projects p join u.accounts a where u.id = :id
```

Comment: This is where you start https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracore/blog/2015/07/search-jira-like-a-boss-with-jql

Comment: Thanks but my bad, mean't to ask how to transform to JPA QL..

Comment: It doesn't seem like you've actually tried anything. Why don't you start by trying something and then you can ask an actual question. Just reading through that link it actually looks pretty straightforward with helpers and drop downs

Comment: Hi Nick, yes I have tried to transform the Query into JPA QL and can get all projects for an account, but getting stuck after that.  So far I have.  select p from Account a join a.project p where a.id = 21, but how to get all the accounts for a user and thus all the projects is eluding me.

Comment: Going by your latest attempt, you need to join all tables. Currently you aren't and that's why you are getting double ups. `join` is just shorthand for `inner join`, and it looks like JPA doesn't use `as`. So it should be pretty straightforward to convert. I suggest you just add one table at a time and experiment. Always `join` the table each time

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Nick, finally got there, was simpler that I had imagined.

Comment: That’s great. You should write it up in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick....

```
select distinct p 
from Project, 
Account a, 
User u 
join a.projects p 
join u.accounts a where u.id = :id
```

If anyone has a better one I would be very interested :)